# How to do "select count(*)" on ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

How can I do a **"select count(*)"** using ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Count()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.count.aspx) LINQ operator. If you're using C#, there isn't anything in the query expression syntax to cover this, so you have to do call it with dot-notation.